# how to disable order for input and options in selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using selectize0.11.0. I have a multiple `<select>`.

I need to do this.

1. Disable order for input of selectize.
2. Disable order for options.

First I select multiple option, and then I sumbmit the form.
Suppose: I select `third` and then I select `first`.

The `<input>` of selectize should be `[third first]`.

When I resubmit the form without changing anything, the page after refresh would not change the order of options in `<select>` and texts in `<input>`.

The select code:

```
<select id="id_sel" multiple='multiple'>
    <option selected='selected' value='1'>first</option>
    <option value='2'>second</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='3'>third</option>
</select>
```

What I tried:

```
$('#{{ filterform.plf.auto_id }}').selectize({maxItem:2});
plf_sel = $('#{{ filterform.plf.auto_id }}')[0].selectize;
plf_sel.clear();
plf_sel.clearOptions();
plf_sel.renderCache['option'] = {};
plf_sel.renderCache['item'] = {};
plf_sel.addOption(plf_sel_option);
plf_sel.setValue(plf_sel_option[0].value);
//plf_sel.setValue(plf_sel_option[1].value);
```

I lost a value, since `setValue` only set one value to be selected.

I put it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdouble/77o34tfe/6/)jsfiddle, but It can not [simulate](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdouble/77o34tfe/5/) submit. how to do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I change `setValue()` to `addItems()` to solve that problem, since [setValue()](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/src/selectize.js#L710) clear all items first and then add item by calling [addItems()](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/src/selectize.js#L1292) once.